# Is there anyway automatically accept clone notifications in sitecore?

Tags: c#, sitecore

I have a sitecore item which has been cloned from another sitecore item. When I add a child item to the parent I want it to add the item under the clone also. It does this but I have to accepts every change manually. I've got 250 clones!

[image]
Is there a way to automatically accept these notifications or prevent them form doing this in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [this article from sitecore](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2010/10/sitecore-cms-6-4-cloning.aspx) someone asks a similar question in the comments section:

> When you create a new subitem for an item that has been clones, it
>   seems you have to manually go to each clone and accept that a subitem
>   be created beneath the clone. Is there any way to not have to do this?
>   For a new solution we will have several clones of one source and the
>   customer won't want to go to every single clone and accept a subitem.
>   It would be much easier and user friendly to have subitems always
>   appear in the clones without any questions. The same also applies to
>   instances where content authors has overridden a value in a clone,
>   then a "power author" changes a value in the source item. How can this
>   change be applied to all clones without the clones having to manually
>   accept the change? Cheers

sitecore have posted a reply with some pseudo code. Basically this translates into the following:

### Build an event class

```
public abstract class AcceptCloneNotificationsEventBase<T> where T : Notification
{
    protected abstract bool ShouldAcceptNotification(Item item, Item parent);

    public void AcceptClone_SavedItem(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var item = (Item)Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0);
        var parent = item.Parent;
        foreach (var clone in item.GetClones())
        {
            foreach (var notification in clone.Database.NotificationProvider.GetNotifications(clone.Uri))
            {
                if (notification is T && ShouldAcceptNotification(item, parent)) 
                {
                    notification.Accept(clone);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void AcceptClone_CreateItem(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var item = (Item)Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0);
        var parent = item.Parent;
        foreach (var clone in parent.GetClones())
        {
            foreach (var notification in clone.Database.NotificationProvider.GetNotifications(clone.Uri))
            {
                if (notification is T && ShouldAcceptNotification(item, parent)) 
                {
                    notification.Accept(clone);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've built this as an `abstract` class so I can utilise it multiple times. The implementation looks like:

```
public class ImplementationOfBase: 
             AcceptCloneNotificationsEventBase<FieldChangedNotification>
{
    protected override bool ShouldAcceptNotification(Item item, Item parent)
    {
        return /*filter the event as you see fit here*/;
    }
}
```

### Register events

```xml
<events>
  <event name="item:added">
    <handler type="Namespace.ImplementationOfBase,Namespace" method="AcceptClone_CreateItem"/>
  </event>
  <event name="item:saved">
    <handler type="Namespace.ImplementationOfBase,Namespace" method="AcceptClone_SavedItem"/>
  </event>
</events>
```